# Making images draggable to HTML5 Canvas, moving images out of canvas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a custom avatar maker, where my users can drag & drop images to the position they want (clothes etc. I take the image urls from database based on what they own). Then they can save the look as png image to my site (using php).  I have no experience on javascript/jquery but I don't think that this can be without them. So I've found amazing code for this from here:

http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/2012/10/export-and-save-a-screenshot-of-an-html5-canvas-using-php-jquery-and-easeljs/

But the images are already in the canvas and can't go outside of it, which is bad considering that someone could have 100 pieces of clothing and didn't want to display them all. Also I have to make custom code for each piece, which is also bad because not all users have the same images to drag.

Is there a way to put all images draggable (to the canvas), so I could easily add the image urls from my database as basic html/css? Is it possible that the images would be outside of the canvas first? Or should I create another canvas for the items users don't want?

Comment: Hmmm...sounds more like a design decision than a coding problem. I guess you could create html ordered lists of images for the clothing options. The user selects 1 from the shirt list, 1 from the pants list, etc. Then you add only the selected images on the canvas for the users. If the user changes their mind and selects a different shirt from the ordered list, you remove the previous shirt image from canvas and add the newly selected shirt. And yes, easeljs is controlled through javascript so you will need to "learn-up" on js coding. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script in the article uses a static image because its goal is only explain how to export a canvas to bitmap : )

I have written another small article where I describe how to upload N images from your hard drive into a canvas ( using CreateJS ) so as you can see the process to load dynamic sources is not so hard.

http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/2012/10/upload-images-from-the-user-hard-driveto-an-html5-canvas-easel-js-application/

Anyway, if you need to load an image into a canvas you can simply use a syntax like this:

```
var img = new createjs.Bitmap('http://uri/image.jpg')
img.x = 50;
img.y = 50;
stage.addChild(img)
stage.update();
```

and if you need to know when an image is completely loaded you should listen for the onload event:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = onImageLoaded;
image.src = "http://uri/image.jpg";

function onImageLoaded (event) {
  var img = new createjs.Bitmap(event.target)
  img.x = 50;
  img.y = 50;
  stage.addChild(img)
  stage.update();
}
```

hope it's useful

Comment: Thanks I got it working exactly as I wanted when I added few pieces of coding here and there (: It wasn't as hard as I first thought it would be!

Comment: In fact! Glad to help :)